# How to calculate the Hausdorff Distance between two points?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, scikit-learn, distance

I am trying to create a distance metric for classification in sklearn.
I can find distance between two sets of such dimensions: `X = {sort_1, sort_2, sort_3, feat_id, feat_val}`-

But to I am confused as to how do I use this for classification in sklearn since for that I need to define the distance as *the distance between two points such that each point is a row.*

Same point represented in one row: `A = {sort_1, sort_2, sort_3, feat_1, feat_2, .... feat_57}`

How do I go about calculating **Hausdorff Distance** between two such rows in python?

Comment: I didn't know the Hausdorff Distance, but after reading the wikipedia page, I'm thinking that this distance os only for sets? Maybe you should tell us more about this. Maybe what output are you expecting for a given input?

Comment: @XavierC. Of course, it also works for two sets that each contains only one point. But then the Hausdorff distance is just the distance in between the points (in the metric that you've chosen). But Ninad T is probably looking for the distance in between sets `A` and `B`, which are both subsets of `R`. Since this might be just a 1D problem, the metric doesn't matter.

Comment: @Ninad T In case I was right above (i.e. we have a 1D setup), you can sort `A`, then iterate through `B` and for each `x` in `B` perform a binary search in the sorted `A`. Let `l` and `r` be the values in the sorted `A` such that `l<=x<=r`. Determine `dist(x,A)=min(abs(l-x),abs(r-x))` for each `x` in `B`. Then switch the roles of `A` and `B` and determine `dist(y,B)` for each `y` in `A`. The Hausdorff distance should be the maximum of these distances.

Comment: @cobarzan, you are correct to an extent, to represent this in 3-dimension x = feat_1, y = feat_2, z = feat_3. But there exists a problem, can sort still be allowed in such a situation?

Comment: @XavierC., I am trying to define a new distance metric for a sklearn classification algorithm, since Euclidean distance fails at very high dimensions I am thinking of using Hausdorff Distance here, check the edited question for more details .